# Sharepoint List name is appearing different in web Address

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

We have created one list its name is => "MobileTechSupport"
but in Web Address(below) it is appearing as "ALL%20MOBILE%20Documents"
below is the whole web address=>
http://studysite/sites/tools/DemoTour/Lists/ALL%20MOBILE%20Documents/MyViewIssue.aspx

We also have created one view its name is "MyViewIssue"
Web address of this view: 
"http://studysite/sites/tools/DemoTour/Lists/ALL%20MOBILE%20Documents/MyViewIssue.aspx"

I have following questions

1) How to remove "%20" from Web Address?

2) Why List name is appearing different in web Address?

3) Can I change  List name which is appearing in Web Address "ALL MOBILE Documents"  to Actual List name "MobileTechSupport"

Thanks in Advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have renamed your list from `All Mobile Documents` to `MobileTechSupport`.

SharePoint sets the web address to the initial name of the list. Even if you rename the List Title thereafter, it doesn't affect in web address.

1. You cannot remove it. Your only option is to delete this and recreate it with a name that does not contain spaces - `%20` is an [URL encoded representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of this particular character.
2. Already answered.
3. No

Comment: The above comment that you cannot remove the space is incorrect. As noted below by Soulful you can change this in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Designer (external SharePoint tool) lets you change the web address (the root folder name) of the list. In SharePoint Designer you must go into the "all files" view and then navigate to the "lists" folder. Inside the "lists" folder you see all your lists and can rename their root folders.